# How to create a path distance matrix?

Tags: qgis-3

I have a point layer with multiple points and a layer with the starting point (fire station).

In the end, I want to create a contour file with distances. But in such a way that the approximate distance is given and not the direct distance.

My question is:
How can I create the lines between points and the lines must be connected to the nearest point.

[image: Base plate]

I want wo be able to measure the distance approximatley by road and not the direct distance (see below).

[image: I want to see the distance of this]

Comment: I think as a first step you need to convert your roads into lines. I am not aware of a method routing along points.

Comment: Anita Graser (aka underdark) has posted information on QGIS routing that may help you: https://anitagraser.com/2019/07/07/five-qgis-network-analysis-toolboxes-for-routing-and-isochrones/

Comment: Also, in your first sentence, do you mean "... A point layer with multiple *points*... ?